# How to prove complex function limits

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a complex function which first I have to turn it into the standard form of the complex function. $$z =x + yi$$

How can I prove this limit using ?

$$\lim_{z\to 2i}(2x+iy^2) =4i$$

Comment: @user90369- I want to prove It in recursive way. I knew the way you solve

Comment: @user90369- Basic level proof.

Comment: What is a "recursive proof" ?

Comment: I want to prove that there is |z-z0| < lambda where z0 is the value of limit.

Comment: @user90369- You have to finally reach to, $$|z-4i| < sth $$

Comment: Then use the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally you can do the following

We have $2x= z + \bar z$.
Similarly $y= \frac{1}{2i} (z - \bar z)$ which implies that $y^2 = - \frac{1}{4} (z^2+ {\bar z}^2 - 2 z\bar z)$.

Now we replace to get that $$ \begin{align}2x+iy^2 &= z + \bar z + - \frac{i}{4} (z^2+ {\bar z}^2 - 2 z\bar z)\\
 \end{align} $$
Hence $$\lim_{z\to 2i}(2x+iy^2) = 2i-2i - \frac{i}{4} ( -4 -4 - 8) = 4i $$